# How can I make a Python module act as a reference for another module?

Tags: python, python-import

I want to ask if there's a nice way to have a module basically act as an alias for another module.

So here's the basic story. For a project at work, we're looking at slowly transitioning some key functionality (our data science pipeline) from one repository to another. As a part of this, we're thinking of moving some key libraries from one repo to another, and I'll probably have the new repo be a git submodule of the old one.

Unfortunately, just moving the key libraries to the new repo won't be a simple matter of a file-move (there's a lot that imports from the module, which would be a number of annoying import changes). So, my bright idea was to move the "real" module to the new repo, make the old module file import from the real module, and then in some fashion everything could import correctly.

So, I'm imagining my old module `important_library.py` as looking something like:

```
from annoying.importpath.to.new.repo.important_library import *
```

But I know this won't work properly.

Is there a graceful way to do this? Maybe I need to put something in `__init__.py`? Or should I just reference all the function and variable names in the old module?

Comment: Check out [patching/mocking](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html). You can use your new code as mocks of the old repository, and once you've mocked EVERYTHING with new stuff, just delete the `patch` decorators, and you should be fine

Comment: Why won't that work properly?